# Como fazer um botão "Ler Mais" em JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Olá.

Tenho esse texto:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent
>   aliquam vitae elit in lobortis. Morbi tincidunt enim elit, condimentum
>   accumsan dolor lacinia elementum. Proin magna nunc, interdum in
>   posuere eu, vestibulum sit amet ante. In dictum justo at lorem rhoncus
>   pretium. Vestibulum vel lorem quis ante tristique vulputate ut sit
>   amet libero. Donec in condimentum erat. Etiam et lorem at metus
>   malesuada pretium in a est.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit. Praesent aliquam vitae elit in lobortis. Morbi
>   tincidunt enim elit, condimentum accumsan dolor lacinia elementum.
>   Proin magna nunc, interdum in posuere eu, vestibulum sit amet ante. In
>   dictum justo at lorem rhoncus pretium. Vestibulum vel lorem quis ante
>   tristique vulputate ut sit amet libero. Donec in condimentum erat.
>   Etiam et lorem at metus malesuada pretium in a est

E preciso criar um botão Ler Mais(ReadMore) utilizando JavaScript.

Preciso que no inicio so apareça esse tamanho:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent
>   aliquam vitae elit in lobortis. Morbi tincidunt enim elit, condimentum
>   accumsan dolor lacinia elementum. Proin magna nunc, interdum in
>   posuere eu, vestibulum sit amet ante. In dictum justo at lorem rhoncus
>   pretium. Vestibulum vel lorem quis ante tristique vulputate ut sit
>   amet libero. Donec in condimentum erat. Etiam et lorem at metus
>   malesuada pretium in a est.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
>   adipiscing elit. Praesent aliquam vitae elit in lobortis. Morbi
>   tincidunt enim elit, condimentum accumsan dolor lacinia elementum.
>   Proin magna

E quando apertar no botão ler mais apareça todo o texto.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Caso nao seja o que postei, explique melhor e se possivel, poste o codigo do que ja tentou fazer :D

Comment: Veja se as resposta desta pergunta não serve https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/169216/como-fazer-anima%C3%A7%C3%A3o-para-mostrar-o-resto-do-par%C3%A1grafo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
    var showChar = 100;  
    var ellipsestext = "...";
    var moretext = "Show more >";
    var lesstext = "Show less";
    

    $('.more').each(function() {
        var content = $(this).html();
 
        if(content.length > showChar) {
 
            var c = content.substr(0, showChar);
            var h = content.substr(showChar, content.length - showChar);
 
            var html = c + '<span class="moreellipses">' + ellipsestext+ '&nbsp;</span><span class="morecontent"><span>' + h + '</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="" class="morelink">' + moretext + '</a></span>';
 
            $(this).html(html);
        }
 
    });
 
    $(".morelink").click(function(){
        if($(this).hasClass("less")) {
            $(this).removeClass("less");
            $(this).html(moretext);
        } else {
            $(this).addClass("less");
            $(this).html(lesstext);
        }
        $(this).parent().prev().toggle();
        $(this).prev().toggle();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```css
.morecontent span {
    display: none;
}
.morelink {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span class="more">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </span>
    <br><br>
    <div class="more">
      Morbi placerat imperdiet risus quis blandit. Ut lobortis elit luctus, feugiat erat vitae, interdum diam. Nam sit amet arcu vitae justo lacinia ultricies nec eget tellus. Curabitur id sapien massa. In hac <a href="#">habitasse</a> platea dictumst. Integer tristique leo consectetur libero pretium pretium. Nunc sed mauris magna. Praesent varius purus id turpis iaculis iaculis. Nulla <em>convallis magna nunc</em>, id rhoncus massa ornare in. Donec et feugiat sem, ac rhoncus mauris. Quisque eget tempor massa.
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado! E isso mesmo que procuro.